# How can I include a txt file in an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, project, nsbundle

I added a file "IntegerArray.txt" as follows, first I went to File -> Add file to "project name", I selected my file and it was copied into the root folder of my project, the same one that contains the .xcodeproj file. Then I clicked on my project's .xcodeproj file in Xcode, after which I went to Build Phases -> Copy Files -> "IntegerArray.txt", however when I build my project, the following code doesn't work

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("IntegerArray", ofType: "txt")
println(path)
```

I expect to see the path to the file as output, but instead I see nil.

So I want to copy a file to my project in such a way  that the above code works. How can I do this?

If I have a normal Cocoa Application, then when I add files they are automatically copied to the built program's bundle. However, with Command Line Tool's this doesn't seem to be the case, I'm starting to suspect a bug with Xcode.

Comment: The code should work; it's likely the file is not being copied into the bundle resources.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't have a Resources directory in your project, select your project:

[image]

Then from the File Menu select Add Files:

[image]

In the window that opens click on the "New Folder" button in the lower left hand corner of the window.

A small pop-up window will open; type Resources in that window for the folder name then click the "Create" button.  You should now have a Resources folder in your project.

Then the way I do it is to use Finder to copy the file into the Resources Directory of my project.

After the file is in the Resources Directory (in Finder), back in Xcode select the Resources directory in your project:

[image]

and use the File-> Add Files menu selection again.  You should see your file highlighted (affineOutput.txt in this case):

[image]

Double Click on it and it will become part of the bundle.

As Milliways says, then check the Build Phases in your project to be sure the file is in the Copy Bundle Resources.  If it's somewhere else, just drag it into the Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: I have followed all the above steps and my file still isn't being copied.

Comment: So you have a Resources folder in your project?

Comment: If you have a Resources folder in your project, does it show your .txt file?

Comment: I'm happy to walk you through this, it's actually pretty straightforward.  If your answer is yes to both of the above, we'll move onto the next step.

Comment: No I don't have a resources folder.

Comment: @jwlaugton, how do I create one?

Answer (score 1):

If you include in the `Resources` Folder it should be included.

You may need to select the `Project` and `Target`.
 In `Build Phases` check is there is entry under `Copy Bundle Resources`